# Prove that a set is a topology.

Tags: general-topology

So I know the definition of topology but I find it really difficult to know what to do to prove a given set is a topology.
I was wondering if someone could talk me through a few problems.

$\tau_1=\{\emptyset, \Bbb R, (-a,a): a \in \Bbb R, a>0\}$

$\tau_2=\{\emptyset, \Bbb R, [-a,a]: a \in \Bbb R, a>0\}$

$\tau_3=\{\emptyset,\Bbb R,[−n,n],(−a,a) : a \in \Bbb R, a > 0, n\in \Bbb N>0\}$

(i) X and the empty set, Ø, belong to τ ,
(ii) the union of any (finite or infinite) number of sets in τ belongs to τ, and
(iii) the intersection of any two sets in τ belongs to τ.

Are the three things that X must satisfy to be a topology.

Thanks

Comment: Remind us of the definitions, please.

Comment: A topology on a set $X$ is a collection of subsets of $X$, $\tau$, such that $\emptyset, X \in \tau$, $\tau$ is closed under arbitrary unions, i.e., if $\{U_a\}_{a \in A} \subset \tau$, $\cup_{a \in A} U_a \in \tau$ for any $A$, and closed under finite intersections, i.e., if $|A| < \infty$ and $\{U_a\}_{a \in A} \subset \tau$, $\cap_{a \in A} U_a \in \tau$. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I just don't know where to start.

Comment: The thing about definitions is that they often come with an *exact recipe* for how to determine when something is an X. You want to determine whether a set of subsets is a topology? Easy! Just check that each part of the definition is satisfied.

Comment: yeah, and I can do the obvious one, saying that (i) is satisfied but after that I don't know.

Comment: For $\tau_2$, what about the union of all $[-a_n, a_n]$ with $a_n=1-1/n$?

Answer (score 1):

Here $X=\mathbb R$. you should check this conditions(A is a subset of $P(\mathbb R))$:

1) $\emptyset \in A$

2)$\mathbb R \in A$

3)closed under finite intersections.

4)closed under arbitrary unions.

since, all the given sets satisfy 1,2, check the conditions 3,4.

Comment: I assume $\phi$ is supposed to be the empty set, but the correct symbol for that is $\emptyset$, which you get with `\emptyset`.

Comment: I fixed it already ;-)

Answer (score 0):

So I'm sure you know but the following three axioms must hold for a set to be a topology:

(i) $\emptyset,X\in\tau$

(ii) $U_1,U_2\in\tau\Rightarrow U_1\cap U_2\in \tau$

(iii) $(U_\alpha)_{\alpha\in \Bbb A}\Rightarrow \cup_{\alpha\in\Bbb A}U_\alpha\in \tau$, where $\Bbb A$ is an arbitrary index.

So what we want to do is show that these axioms hold, if they don't then the collection is not a topology on $X$.

1st example: $X=\Bbb R$.

(i) does $\emptyset,\Bbb R\in \tau_1$? yes we can see from the set definition you have been given.

(ii) Let $U_1,U_2\in\tau_1$ where $U_1=(-b,b),U_2=(-a,a)$ with loss of generality we must have either $a\le b$ or $b\le a$, let us assume $a\le b$, then in fact $U_2\subset U_1$

Thus $U_1\cap U_2=U_2\in\tau_1$ thus (ii) holds.

(iii) Take the family $(U_\alpha)_{\alpha\in\Bbb A}$, where $U_\alpha=(-K_\alpha,K_\alpha)$ for some $K_\alpha\in\Bbb R$

We see that $\cup_{\alpha\in\Bbb A}U_\alpha=\cup_{\alpha\in\Bbb A}(-K_\alpha,K_\alpha)\in \tau_1$ since the arbitrary union of open intervals in $\Bbb R$ is an open interval. Thus (iii) holds

Thus $\tau_1$ is a topology on $\Bbb R$

Comment: @ZZS14 I would be happy to go over the others if need be, but it would probably be beneficial to those one's yourself, all you have to do is work with the sets to show that all of the axioms hold, or show that one does not (making it not a topology)

Comment: I will have a try now. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, happy to help :)

Comment: so does it follow in the same way for the topology $T_1$={$\theta$,R,[−a,a]:a∈R,a>0}

Comment: @ZZS14
In this case $\cup_{n=2}^\infty[-1+\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}]=(-1,1)\nexists \tau_2$

Comment: @ZZS14 so in this case no $\tau_2$ is not a topology as we can find an arbitrary unioin of elements of $\tau_2$ that is not in $\tau_2$

Comment: Can you explain (iii) I don't know why you would do that.

Comment: for $\tau_1$ or $\tau_2$?

Comment: $\tau_1$ I understand it but I wouldn't know why to put that or where to start from :(

Comment: Okay, basically you want to make the statement as general as possible, because "arbitrary unions" basically means I can take any union I please and it will still be in $\tau_1$.

We are in a good position, because any element in $\tau_1$ is an open interval in $\Bbb R$, and we know that any arbitrary union of open intervals in $\Bbb R$ produces an open interval.

This is exactly what I have put :)

Comment: Okay thanks, I will work through the others (or try to) now!